# Applying arthimetic formula on 2 data frames mapping them by column

Tags: r

I have 2 matrices.
A, B
A has 100 rows and 350 columns 
B has 1 rows and 350 columns(in the exact same order as they are in A)

I want the third data frame matrix C which will have 100 rows and 350 columns
Value in any cell in C will be x * A + (1-x) * B for the same corresponding column values in A and B respectively.

I can correctly do this by applying various/multiple loops but it is taking a lot of time.

Is there any direct method to apply this formula in one go on all the 350 columns (as the order/index of all the columns in all the matrices A, B, C are same)

Comment: What's `x` in your formula?

Comment: Does B have 1 row or 100 rows?

Comment: If `A` and `B` have the same number of rows/columns and `x` is a scalar, then `function(A, B, x) {A*x + B*(1-x)}` will do the job.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a _minimal_ example of both input and desired output. Just enough rows/cols to illustrate your point, not more, not less. See [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and [**here**](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: There is a bug in the question. The formula seems to be the usual linear interpolation x A + (1-x) B, x from [0, 1] between A and B, where A and B should have same dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `x` is a constant, all you should need is:

```
t(apply(x*A, 1, `+`, B*(1-x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A<-matrix(runif(35000),nrow=100)
B<-matrix(1:350,nrow=1)

x<-2                                       # or whatever

B.M<-matrix(rep(B,100),nrow=100,byrow=T)   # expand B out to same size

(x * A) + ((1-x) * B.M)
```